# How to call a function after completion of another function using callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

```js
function one(){
    console.log(1);
}
function two(callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(2);
    },2000);
    callback();
}
two(one);
```

While I am running this code, 1 is displaying first and then 2 because 2 is taking 2 second time to display. Suppose if there is an api instead of console.log(2) in function two which is taking 2 second to respond, so How I can call function one after completion of function two using callback(); which I can do in this case if I use callback() inside setTimeout function but what if there is an api where I am not using setTimeout and it's taking 2-3 second?

Comment: You can call api with `async` - `await`, so that 2nd function will be called after api call is completed :)

Comment: I want to call 2nd function first which is taking longer time then function 1 using callback. Is that possible?

Comment: call your `second function` first with `async` and then call the `first function` on completing `second`. Simple.  Bro think simple it will resolve all questions

Answer (score 4):

Even if there is an `api` call which takes time to resolve, you can still use a callback at the same way you just did with the `setTimeout` example.

Alternatively, use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function two(callback) {
    new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res();
        }, 2000);
    }).then(callback)
}
```

or using [`async/await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) syntax:

```
async function two(callback) {
    await new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res();
        }, 2000);
    })
    callback();
}
```

Comment: Earlier I was thinking we can do it without using promise or async but we have to use it. This is helpful though. Thank you.

Comment: @MohdAyazurRahmanShaikh You can simply use a `callback` like in your example if you want to avoid using `Promises`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promises:

```js
function one(){
    console.log(1);
}

function two(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(()=>{
         console.log(2);
         resolve()
      },2000);
    })
}

two().then(() => one())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sync function like this

```js
function two() {//this function takes 2 seconds
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
function one(){
    console.log("one");
}
async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  const result = await two();
 one()
  // expected output: 'resolved'
}

asyncCall();
```

here is reference [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 0):

Put `callback();` inside `setTimeout`:

```js
function one(){
    console.log(1);
}
function two(callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(2);
        callback();
    },2000);
    
}
two(one);
```

Comment: I have mentioned it in question that I can do this if I put callback() inside setTimeout but what if I don't use setTimeout and still that particular code is taking 2-3 second like while we call api, it might take longer time.

Comment: @MohdAyazurRahmanShaikh let's say you will end up using `request`, you will have a `success` callback wherein you can perform any action AFTER the execution